# Pass variables from function to function

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I'm just learning Objective-C and have a what I'm sure is a pretty basic question here.
This is a function I've created that will simple hold variables from some user input.

```
- (void)standardDatabaseWithName:(NSString*)name 
                            host:(NSString*)host 
                        username:(NSString*)username 
                        password:(NSString*)password
                        database:(NSString*)database
                            port:(NSInteger*)port {

  NSString *myName = name;
  NSString *myHost = host;
  NSString *myUsername = username;
  NSString *myPassword = password;
  NSString *myDatabase = database;
  NSInteger *myPort = port;
}
```

Below is a seperate function where I want to create a new var with that information and the from there use it was what I need.

```
- (void)insertStandardConnection {
    NSString name = [NewDbModalView standardDatabaseWithName:myName];
    NSString host = [NewDbModalView standardDatabaseWithName:myHost]; 
}
```

So this attempt didn't work for me. Any advice here guys? At this point I've been left scratching my head.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest creating an object to hold all of that information and just pass the object around

Answer (score 0):

Every time you call the method, you have to provide all of the variables:

```
[NewDbModalView standardDatabaseWithName:myName host:myHost username:aUsername password:aPassword database:aDatabase port:aPort];
```

So, when you call `[NewDbModalView standardDatabaseWithName:myName]`, that method doesn’t exist.

Comment: Hey, thanks that makes sense. So the reason I was hoping my method would work is because I need to, at certain point, only target one of these var. So say I've done what you suggesting and only need to work with the username for example. How can I target that?

Comment: You can create methods to do each of those. So if you only need to change the password, make a `-setPassword:` method.

Answer (score 0):

The variables you declare in `standardDatabaseWithName:...` are local to that method.  You need to store (copies of) that data inside the object.  Although, looking at your code, I wonder if you're trying to set default values?  In that case, you might want static global variables to take the values, and then you'd need `-(void)standardDatabaseWithName:...` to become `+(void)setStandardDatabaseName:(NSString *)name ...`.

Answer (score 0):

In  your .h file you should declare properties

```
    @interface standardDatabaseWithNameObject : NSObject{
    NSString *myName;
    NSString *myHost;
    NSString *myUsername ;
    NSString *myPassword;
    NSString *myDatabase;
    NSInteger *myPort;
    }

    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *myName;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *myHost;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *myUsername ;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *myPassword;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *myDatabase;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSInteger *myPort;
etc...
```

Then in your implementation you need to synthesize the properties and they will be available for use:

```
@synthesize myName, myHost, myUsername, myPassword, myDatabase, myPort;


- (void)standardDatabaseWithName:(NSString*)name 
                            host:(NSString*)host 
                        username:(NSString*)username 
                        password:(NSString*)password
                        database:(NSString*)database
                            port:(NSInteger*)port {

  myName = name;
  myHost = host;
  myUsername = username;
  myPassword = password;
  myDatabase = database;
  myPort = port;
}

- (void)insertStandardConnection {
    NSString name = myName;
    NSString host = myHost; 
}

- (void) dealloc
{
[myName release];
[myHost release];
[myUsername release];
[myPassword release];
[myDatabase release];
[myPort release];

}
```

Good Luck

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot. You've made that pretty crystal clear. So when passing that amount or info around. It's probably always cleaner to create a separate object, correct?

Comment: All of those need to be self.myName, etc, or the above code won't be following the retain/release rules...

Comment: Shane, depending on where you need the data, you should store it on that particular level. If you only need it within a function, then declare it in the function. If you need it in the object, then declare it as a property. If you need to globally, then declare it globally. -- Also bbum is right, you want to deallocate your variables at some point as to  not create a memory leak.